# How can I remove all items from the cart in PHP?

Tags: php, html, session-cookies, session-variables

I already have some items in the cart. I want to remove them all. So, I've created a submit button with post method called 'remove_all', following doesn't work, it says "The requested URL was not found on this server." Can please someone help me?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['remove_all'])){
            unset($_SESSION['cart']);
            echo "<script>window.location = 'cart.php'</script>";
        }
?>
```

And here what I wrote in my index.php

```
<form action="remove_all" method="post" class="cart-items">
<button type="submit" value="Очистить всё" name="remove_all" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">Очистить всё</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe your php script is called `remove_all.php` rather than just `remove_all`? Just a guess obviously since we cannot see your server. You need to check the URL you've put in your form's action...we cannot do that for you based on the information provided. Your problem is nothing to do with carts or sessions

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you you not linking properly to your remove_all.php file. Try this:

```
<form action="/remove_all.php" method="post" class="cart-items">
<button type="submit" value="Очистить всё" name="remove_all" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">Очистить всё</button>
</form>
```

Also in your PHP file, you do not need to mix PHP and js - simply change header as following:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['remove_all'])){
            unset($_SESSION['cart']);
            // echo "<script>window.location = 'cart.php'</script>";
            header("Location: cart.php");
        }
?>
```